# What does stochastic nature of work (quantum scale) really mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, stochastic-processes, fluctuation-dissipation

[Fluctuation theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation_theorem) are (also) concerned with defining work in the non-equilibrium regime.

Now I've read that in regimes where Fluctuations become very strong (which I assume are the non-equilibrium regime and regimes of very small scales such as quantum regime) thermodyanmic quantities such as work or heat become random variables.

> On these very short (quantum) length scales, thermal as well as quantum
>   fluctuations become important, and usual thermodynamic quantities,
>   such as work and heat, acquire a stochastic nature.

I'd like to discuss the implications of this. What does it mean if work is a stochastic quantity?

To better understand this I was thinking of a mini-cilinder, where we change some external parameter such as the volume by pushing in a piston. 
Apparently the stochasatic nature would imply that if we push in the piston with the **same force** multiple times the work performed by/on the system can be different from case to case. 
And only in limits of large repetitions we get a average value which is somewhat reliable.

Is this the correct way to think about it? (mind you for now I am only interested in work).

Also: Does this stochastic nature only occur on small quantum scales, or is this the case for non-equilibrium regime aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search about Jarzynski equality and Crooks relation. They deal exactly with this, with implication to second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Quick hint : Assuming system under consideration is isolated. (i) Every time system is prepared, its microstate varies (same source of randomness as for classical setup) . (ii) For quantum case, work (so as to satisfy FT of Jarzynski/Bochkov-Kuzelov) is defined through two energy measurements, this is another source of randomness (unique for quantum case).